# iOS 3.0+ compatibility for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, compatibility

I've released an app but forgot to set the compatibility to iOS 3.0+, can I make an update to support 3.0+ and how?
Should I just change the deployment target to 3.0 and is there a way to test it in simulator for 3.0?
I only have 4.2 and 4.3 for debug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your deployment target to 3.0 and test it in the simulator. If all goes well, submit it as an update - exactly as you described.

When you change deployment targets to 3.0, you should be able to select the 3.0 simulator in the schemes.

Comment: Maybe I use some methods that are not supported in version lower than 4.0?

In simulator I can choose 4.0, 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3

Comment: hmm....I just checked in my Xcode, you're right - the only simulators I see are 4.0, 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3 

However - I think Xcode will warn you if you use methods not supported in your deployment target.

Comment: So if I've set the deployment target to 3.0 and run it in 4.3 simulator, does that mean that it will work on iOS 3.0?

Comment: @Karuna-bdc - **Extremely bad advice!** Final testing should allways be done **on device** with at least the oldest supported OS version, and on a device with the latest version *(Also make sure to test the upgrade process)*. The simulator is **far** from a sufficient test tool. Also treating Apple Review board as your external test team is extremely bad behavior, the kind of behavior that forces the rest of us to have week long waits for reviews.

Comment: PeyloW, Yes that is true 

Wikiboo - I apologize for the bad advice, you should test on the device and not rely on the Review board as PeyloW said

@PeyloW - What if we do not have access to OS 3.0 device? do you have any work around to suggest?

Comment: @Karuna-bdc - Apart from keeping all old devices when I buy a new one, I also bought a handful of used and cheap iPod touches for testing purposes.

Answer (score 4):

Change your deployment target to iPhone OS 3.0 and test **on device** with iPhone OS 3.0.

Not only is it bad practice to even consider deploying to App Store before testing on device. If version compatibility is your concern it is doubly so, since the Simulator is far from perfect when in comes to testing all version incompatibilities.

Also ask yourself if you really need to support iPhone OS 3.0 users? All studies made tells us that around 95% of all users are running on iOS 4.0 and later.

A user who can not be bothered to update to the latest OS version for free, is not likely to pay for your app.